# Populate username in the select list ( CCK )

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do populate username's in the select list. i added below code in the Allowed list textbox. But select list showing the PHP code instead of usernames.

```
global $user;
$sql = "SELECT name FROM  users";
$res = db_query($sql);
while($row = db_fetch_array($res)){
$rows[] = $row['name'];
}
return $rows;
```

[image]

Note: Application running in D7.
As well i just followed below steps also.

```
Enable Core module PHP Filter.
Set/Check user permissions: admin/people/permissions#module-php.
Set/Check Text Formats: admin/config/content/formats.
Enable CCK Module. This step is often overlooked. However without CCK Module enabled you wont be able to enter (and thus execute) PHP-code in the Allowed-Values-List window
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try Entity Reference - It works with CCK and allows you to reference Users: https://drupal.org/project/entityreference